# IOS imageView animation Multiple times

Tags: ios, animation, imageview

Okay guys, i have an imageview which i want to animate over some buttons.
I want to move the imageview from a starting point to the finish point.the finish point is dynamically being allocated and the start point gets replaced by the then current end point.

Suppose there are Buttons : b1, b2, b3, b4.

I want to move the imageView from b1 to b4. I am getting the start and end points and i am able to move the imageView form the start to end. But the problem is, I want to move the imageView Step by Step. i.e b1-b2, b2-b3, b3-b4. 
I am using a method which updates the imageView's x and y, dynamically according to the start and finish. 
I have tried calling the same method in a for loop running each time (b1-b2, b2-b3, b3-b4).
But I can only see the movement for the last movement. I have also delayed the method calling by using

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myAnimationMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

But still only the last movement is visible.
Again, i know that i wont be needing this if i use block animations. but i have already tried it and the result is same. And my buttons are not in a straight line, that moving the imageView from start to finish, WILL appear to go button by button, but they are in a zig-zag way, so i DONT want the imageView to go out of its path.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is `for(..)` loop, which doesn't wait for the animations. So what you want to do is, go with the ***GCD*** Or do play with

```
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to define order by assigning `Tag` to the buttons and define next button on which position the imageview will move.. And you should perform animation on the completion of first one, see below..

```
-(void)animate{

    if(nextTag>lastButtonTag)
        return; //STOP

    nextButtonToMove=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:nextTag];
    nextTag++;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        animatableView.center=nextButtonToMove.center;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self animate];//Call the function again on finish
    }];

}
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: I have already assigned tag to my buttons, and i can find the path of the movement too, (the buttons it needs to traverse). I have made a temp array for holding the path of the movement.(array of those buttons it needs to travel). but only the last movement is being displayed.